# How can I plot means?

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I am working on my thesis and I need to compare some means for descriptive statistics. I don't know how to plot these means. I already have the means, so I just need a code for plotting. I want that the plot looks like the one the picture

[image]

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the output of dput(your data) with a minimal number of data points please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add some data (even if it is made up) to exemplify which kind of format the numbers are?